# Run simple Java Swing applicaion (stand alone) in Docker

Tags: java, swing, docker

I am new to Docker and I wrote a simple Java Swing project, which will launch a calculator having 3-4 class files. 
As I went through docker tutorials, I was getting confused. I couldn't find a single tutorial where docker is used for a non-web application with Swing GUI. Can anyone please help me with resolving the following?

Is dockerization possible for standalone application(without client-server concept)?
If yes, how to do that from scratch?

Comment: Question is why would you need anything to be dockerized if you are not gonna do the client-server architecture? You can build and JAR file which is quite portable across environments, right?

Comment: Docker essentially lets your code run in a Linux _server_ which doesn’t have GUI capacity.